# Stripe: Getting Credit Card's Last 4 Digits

Tags: stripe-payments

I have upgraded the Stripe.net to the latest version which is 20.3.0 and now I don't seem to find the .Last4 for the credit card. I had the following method:

```
    public void CreateLocalCustomer(Stripe.Customer stipeCustomer)
    {
        var newCustomer = new Data.Models.Customer
        {
            Email = stipeCustomer.Email,
            StripeCustomerId = stipeCustomer.Id,
            CardLast4 = stipeCustomer.Sources.Data[0].Card.Last4
        };

        _dbService.Add(newCustomer);

        _dbService.Save();
    }
```

But now the `stipeCustomer.Sources.Data[0].Card.Last4` says `'IPaymentSource' does not contain a definition for 'Card'`. Does anyone know how I can get the card details now? The flow is that I create the customer by passing the Stripe token to Stripe, then I get the above stripeCustomer. So I expect it to be somewhere in that object. But I can't find it. The release notes can be found [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/releases).
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills. Ended up debugging. I post the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the old world of Stripe, there only used to be one type of payment method you could attach to a Customer; specifically, [`Card`-objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object).  You would create a [`Card`-object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object) by using [Stripe.js/v2](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/v2) or the [Create Token API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) to *first* create a [`Token`-object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) and *then* attach that token to a [`Customer`-object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) with the [Create Card API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card).

Once Stripe expanded to support a number of other payment methods though, Stripe built support for a new object type that encapsulated a number of payment methods (including credit cards) called [`Source`-objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api#source_object).  A [`Source`-object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#source_object) is created either by using [Stripe.js/v3](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) or the [Create Source API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_source).  It can also be attached to a [`Customer`-object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) in much the same way as the [`Card`-objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object) mentioned above, except they retain their object type.  They're still a `Source`.  You use the [Attach Source API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/attach) to do this (that is notably identical to the [Create Card API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) mentioned above).

What I'm getting at here, is there are now two different object types (or more) that you can expect to see returned in the `sources`-array (or `Sources` in .NET).  All of these methods though inherit from the `IPaymentSource`-interface.  So if you know you have a [`Card`-object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object) getting returned, you can simply cast the returned object to the [`Card`-class](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/Cards/Card.cs).

Something like this should get you going:

```
CardLast4 = ((Card) stipeCustomer.Sources.Data[0]).Last4
```

You can see what I mean by inheritance by looking at this line in the `Card`-class file:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/Cards/Card.cs#L7

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @korben. Yes, I debugged it and realized that I am getting a card object so the casting works. Your answer and mine is the same but I mark yours as it has  a lot of good information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As of `Stripe.net.21.4.1`, this is what works:

```
var chargeService = new ChargeService();
var charge = chargeService.Get(id);    
CardLast4 = ((Card)charge.Source).Last4;
```

It's getting hard not to panic when code breaks because of all the micro-changes Stripe makes.

Answer (score 0):

So after debugging, it looks like the Data[0] needs to be cast as Card to get the card.
So it will be `CardLast4 = ((Card)stipeCustomer.Sources.Data[0]).Last4`.